# unable to read properties using enableconfigurationproperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({GlobalProperties.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        GlobalProperties globalProperties = context.getBean(GlobalProperties.class);
        System.out.println(globalProperties);
    }
}

@PropertySource("classpath:global.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class GlobalProperties {

    private String error;
    private List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<>();
    private Compiler compiler = new Compiler();

//getters and setters and tostring

    public static class Menu {
        private String name;
        private String path;
        private String title;

    //getters and setters and tostring

    }

    public static class Compiler {
        private String timeout;
        private String outputFolder;

    //getters and setters and tostring
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GlobalProperties [error=" + error + ", menus=" + menus + ", compiler=" + compiler + "]";
    }


}
```

global.properties is in src/main/resources

```
#Logging
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.com.mkyong=DEBUG

#Global
email=test@mkyong.com
thread-pool=10

#App
app.menus[0].title=Home
app.menus[0].name=Home
app.menus[0].path=/
app.menus[1].title=Login
app.menus[1].name=Login
app.menus[1].path=/login

app.compiler.timeout=5
app.compiler.output-folder=/temp/

app.error=/error/
```

This is the result when i run the above Application program

```
GlobalProperties [error=null, menus=[], compiler=Compiler{timeout='null', outputFolder='null'}]
```

But if i comment out `@EnableConfigurationProperties({GlobalProperties.class})` annotation on `Application` class and add `@Component` annotation on `GlobalProperties` i am getting expected result

```
GlobalProperties [error=/error/, menus=[Menu{name='Home', path='/', title='Home'}, Menu{name='Login', path='/login', title='Login'}], compiler=Compiler{timeout='5', outputFolder='/temp/'}]
```

Why can't i use enableconfigurationproperty annotation here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@PropertySource` annotation doesn't work without any of `@Component` or `@Configuration` annotations. You must properly register your properties file. You can do somethink like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:global.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties({GlobalProperties.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        GlobalProperties globalProperties = context.getBean(GlobalProperties.class);
        System.out.println(globalProperties);
    }
}
```

Or you can move related properties to `application.properties` file, that configured in spring boot by default.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
@PropertySource("classpath:global.properties")
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class GlobalProperties {

  ......

}
```

You have to use `@ConfigurationProperties` in conjuction with `@Configuration` or `@Component`.

Why ?

Its simple. Unless you have one of these annotations(`@Configuration`, `@Component`, `@Service` ... etc), it is a regular java class and not a spring bean, hencespring will not scan this class during startup. Which means, it cannot inject the properties.

Comment: I got it working with annotating one of the above things, but why can't i use EnableConfigurationProperties without use of component, configuration or service

Comment: Sorry, i think you are wrong. His problem in PropertySource, that really don't work without one of this annotations. But that is unnecessary for @ConfigurationProperties. He can place his properties in application.properties and all will be ok without any change in code.

Comment: As I explained. without one of these annotations, spring will not scan your class during startup. So if it doesn't scan, it will not do anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

GlobalProperties is a POJO the way you defined it, not a Spring Bean.

Annotating the class with @Component or @Configuration will make the class a Spring Bean and you will be able to retrieve it from the Spring Context.

To see how to use @EnableConfigurationProperties I recommend you to check this article: https://spring.io/blog/2013/10/30/empowering-your-apps-with-spring-boot-s-property-support.